# Queryset in an inherited Django Template

Tags: django, templates, django-queryset, inherited

I'm new to Django and Web programming in general. Have googled but could not find the answer I need. Here's the case:

I have a site, where every page in which the user is logged has certain navigation Menu. That's why they extend a template called base_logged.html, which is also extending base.html.
The problem is that the navigation menu is partly populated by a database Query.

Is there a way of populating this without making tha query in every logged view ?
Or some kinda View inheritance?

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to create a custom template tag (probably an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)) and put it in your base template.

So in your base template you could have something like this:

```
{% navigation_bar user %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) ([Here's a good example](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/)). These allow you to make variables (querysets etc.) available in every view throughout your site. For example, make a file in one of your apps:

**some_app.context_processors.my_context_processor.py**

```
from some_app.models import Bar
def my_context_processor():
    return {
        'foo' : Bar.objects.all(),
    }
```

and in your **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'some_app.context_processors.my_context_processor',
    ...
)
```

and you now have access in all your views/templates:

```
{{ foo }}
```

Comment: That sounds nice. I will try it and then post my experience. Doesn't matter that not every page will make sense with the query? Because the query is based in the user...

Comment: `...
def my_context_processor(request):
...`